# Passing parameter to stored procedure using dynamic SQL into pivot data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, pivot

I am trying to pass a parameter into Stored procedure to filter data in my select statement but when i use the parameter it gives error Message: Invalid column name 'SessionId2075'. when I use static value in the where clause the procedure works fine. Can you please give me fix the issue. I checked all the previous answers and could not find the working solution.

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].GetPivotFeeReport
(
@SessionId varchar(50) 
)
as
begin 

DECLARE @SQL as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)



SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @Columns =
COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(GroupHeaderValue)
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT mgh.GroupHeaderValue
    FROM   StudentFeeDetail sf
           INNER JOIN MasterGroupHeaderValue mgh
           ON mgh.GroupHeaderValueId = sf.FeeForId

   ) AS B
ORDER BY B.GroupHeaderValue


SET @SQL = 'SELECT ClassName,' + @Columns + ',TOTAL
FROM
(
 SELECT 
                distinct mc.className,
                sf.FinalAmount,
                mgh.GroupHeaderValue,
                Sum (isnull(sf.FinalAmount,0)) over (partition by ClassName)  AS TOTAL
                --0 AS TOTAL
         FROM   StudentFeeDetail sf 
                INNER JOIN StudentAdmission sa 
                  ON sa.AdmissionId = sf.AdmissionId
                INNER JOIN MasterClass mc
                  ON mc.ClassId = sa.ClassId
                INNER JOIN MasterGroupHeaderValue mgh
                  ON mgh.GroupHeaderValueId = sf.FeeForId
        WHERE   sa.SessionId = (' + @SessionId + ')  -- this is where I am trying to use the parameter when used static value like this ''SessionId2075'' the procedure works fine
        and sf.FeeAmt >0
        GROUP BY className, FinalAmount, GroupHeaderValue

) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
   sum(FinalAmount)
   FOR GroupHeaderValue IN (' + @Columns + ')  
) AS PivotResult

ORDER BY (ClassName) 
'

EXEC ( @sql)


end
```

Comment: I guess when you write your query must be doing WHERE sa.SessionId = 'SessionId2075'. Try this WHERE sa.SessionId = ('' + @SessionId + ''). Its hard to tell without knowing the table definition.

Comment: when I use fixed value like sa.SessionId = SessionId2075 the proc works fine but I want to use parameter @SessionId instead of fixed value

Comment: Add PRINT @sql prior to EXEC(@sql). To debug the SQL Query. That would be the way to debug dynamic sql.

Comment: Thanks I am filter data into temp table before using that in pivot like Select ... into #Temp From StudentFeeDetail where SessionId = @SessionId and use the #Temp table in Pivot . This solved by problem. Thanks